# Rolling standard deviation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have time series data grouped by Object ID. I would like to know how to calculate the standard deviation of all values between today and 4 days ago PER OBJECT, on a rolling basis. I.e:

```
 id      date        value                   stdev
12345   24/11/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   25/11/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   28/11/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   29/11/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   30/11/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   01/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
37470   02/12/2005  0.0001921229586935640   0.0000000826153837838936
37470   05/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000826153837838936
37470   06/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000826153837838937

67890   07/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   08/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   09/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   12/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   13/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   14/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   15/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   16/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   19/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   20/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   21/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   22/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   23/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   26/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   27/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   28/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   29/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   30/12/2005  0.0001923076923076920   0.0000000000000000000000
67890   02/01/2006  0.0001922984471900390   0.0000000041345423064249
```

Comment: Do you mean four days ago or four transactions ago? Your STDEV for id 37470 on the 06/12/2005 suggests you mean transactions instead

Comment: This becomes *way* easier with SQL Server 2012, due shortly (March). Would a solution for this be useful?

Comment: Hi, I mean transactional in that case. A solution would be very useful as I won't have access to 2012 for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
;WITH sample_data AS
(
SELECT 12345 as id,  '2005-11-24' as date, 0.0001923076923076920 as datas 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-11-25' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-11-28' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-11-29' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-11-30' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-12-01' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-12-02' , 0.0001921229586935640 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-12-05' , 0.0001923076923076920 
UNION ALL SELECT 37470 ,  '2005-12-06' , 0.0001923076923076920 
)
,sample_data2 AS
(
SELECT 
id
,date
,datas
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) as row
FROM sample_data
)
,sample_data3 AS
(
SELECT  
sd2.id AS id
,sd2.date as Date
,sd2.datas as orig_data
,sd3.datas as prior_data
FROM sample_data2 sd2
LEFT OUTER JOIN sample_data2 sd3 ON sd3.id = sd2.id
AND sd3.row <= sd2.row
AND sd3.row > sd2.row - 5
AND sd2.row > 0
)
SELECT
 id
,Date
,MAX(orig_data) as Data_value
,ISNULL(STDEV(prior_data),0) AS STDEV_
FROM sample_data3
GROUP BY
id 
,date
```

Comment: Hi, I think that's almost there. But one of the standard deviation calculations is incorrect, just using the sample data listed in the query:

Comment: ID Date Value SQL STDEV ExpectedSTDEV
12345 24/11/2005 0.000192307692307692 0 0
37470 25/11/2005 0.000192307692307692 0 0
37470 28/11/2005 0.000192307692307692 0 0
37470 29/11/2005 0.000192307692307692 2.57244E-12 0
37470 30/11/2005 0.000192307692307692 0 0
37470 01/12/2005 0.000192307692307692 0 0
37470 02/12/2005 0.000192122958693564 8.26154E-08 8.26154E-08
37470 05/12/2005 0.000192307692307692 8.26154E-08 8.26154E-08
37470 06/12/2005 0.000192307692307692 8.26154E-08 8.26154E-08

Comment: Could you post this with DDL code instead so I could test this? Alternatively instead of the last part of the code (SELECT id...GOUP BY date) put SELECT * FROM sample_data3 and let me know which values you don't want included as part of the STDEV calculation.

Comment: hi, all values within the range for the object should be included.

Comment: the following standard deviation should be 0 as the values don't change in the specified range:

Comment: 37470   2005-11-28   0.0001923076923076920   0
37470   2005-11-29   0.0001923076923076920   2.5724394843075E-12