# Standard Deviation of the column with day wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a query to find the standard deviation for a column with daywise. My table has some 30,000 rows with the timestamp of every 10 mins. Please find the below sample data with columns timestamp and TF. i need to get the deviation for rest of the columns as well

```
Timestamp                  TF
2012-05-17 19:15:35.000    10
2012-05-17 19:25:35.000    10
2012-05-17 19:35:35.000    10
2012-05-17 19:45:35.000    10
2012-05-17 19:55:35.000    10
2012-05-17 20:05:35.000    10
2012-05-17 20:15:35.000    10
2012-05-17 20:26:46.000    10
2012-05-18 00:06:48.000    10
2012-05-18 00:16:48.000    10
2012-05-18 00:26:48.000    10
2012-05-18 00:36:48.000    10
2012-05-18 00:46:48.000    10
2012-05-18 00:56:48.000    10
2012-05-18 01:06:48.000    10
2012-05-18 01:16:48.000    10
2012-05-18 01:26:48.000    10
2012-05-18 01:36:49.000    10
```

The need output as

```
Timestamp        TF
2012-05-17     0
2012-05-18       0
---             --
---             --
---             --
---             --
```

Please help!! Thanks in advance!!

Any ideas?

Comment: why doing it here in sql-server. solve it in programmatic way in your server side from the query output.that'll  be easier

Comment: i am new to SQL, i need a query on this. can you help please

Comment: I think your output is not understandable.Can you put more data in it?

Comment: There is a similar post at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034504/rolling-standard-deviation-in-sql-server
Check it might help

Comment: i need to calculate the standard deviation( may be using SQL builtin function) for the mentioned data day wise. In this case the TF column should not be 10 for all the time, and this has to be checked day wise as i have more data recored every ten minutes.. hope this is clear or please let me know i will try to explain more clear

Comment: can you help me posting the query for my requirement. It would be very helpful as i am very new to SQL

Comment: Hi Kamran, can you help me in forming the query please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I transposed `DAY` and `DATE`: `DAY` returns day-of-month; `DATE` returns the time truncated to the day.  Answer is updated to include that fix.

You will need to use an aggregate function, grouping by the day:

```
SELECT DATE(Timestamp), STDDEV(TV) FROM MyTable GROUP BY DATE(Timestamp);
```

I assume there is a `DATE()` function.

There might not be a `STDDEV` function.  If there isn't, `STDDEV(x)=SQRT(AVG((x-AVG(x))^2)`, which might have to be implemented as a joined subquery:

```
SELECT DATE(Timestamp), SQRT(AVG((a.TF-b.mean)*(a.TF-b.mean)) FROM MyTable a LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DATE(Timestamp) day, AVG(TF) mean FROM MyTable GROUP BY DATE(Timestamp)) b
        ON DATE(a.Timestamp)=b.day 
    GROUP BY b.day;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I treid the below query as you posted,
    select DAY(timestamp) as Timestamp,STDEV(TA) as Deviation from   Sensation group by DAY(timestamp)

But i did not get the output as expected, as per the above data, i  need the deviation for the column each date(recorded every ten minutes) i need the only date with deviation for entire day. pleae help

Comment: i got error message 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Ah, it appears my-SQL doesn't have that feature.  A bit of research indicates that replacing `DATE(Timestamp)` with `CAST(Timestamp as DATE)` should fix your problem.